# set non-ORM object fields while querying

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Assume I have a class `Interaction`. My program processes `interactions`, in a way that each interaction updates a score table. `Interaction` is declared as an exact mapping of the database table, but I also want it to have a reference to the relevant instance of `ScoreTable`. `ScoreTable` is a class that holds the scores, and controls the business logic to update scores:

```
class Interaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'interactions'
    #Mirror the table's structure
    anomaly_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('anomalies.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) # ForeignKey('users.id'),
    feedback_score = Column(Integer)

    #scoreUpdater is another (non-ORM) object I want this instance to be aware of
    myScoreUpdater=  ...
```

All instances of `Interaction` fetched by a `query()` will share the same `ScoreUpdater`.So when I run the `query()` to get all my instances of `Interactions`, can I somehow tell the `query()` to set the `scoreUpdater` to a certain value, *in the same process*? Else, can I give `query()` a half-built template instance if `Interaction` to clone and populate the ORM data into?
I read that I could modify the standard constructor to perform certain tasks, but don't know how to pass extra arguments (such as the instance of ScoreUpdater) to the constructor via the `query()`

I guess the other way is to run the `query` first and let it populate the ORM-related fields, and then in a second step, iterate over the query results to set the non-OM fields (i.e. the right instance of scoreUpdater)?

I'm new to SQLalchemy ... and converting from java to python. So if you think my approach is fundamentally wrong, let me know!

Comment: I think I understand your `ScoreUpdater` thinking (though I'd keep business logic separate from model objects), but what exactly is a `ScoreTable`? Is it another mapped class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant [documentation on constructing objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html) says:

> The SQLAlchemy ORM does not call `__init__` when recreating objects from database rows. The ORM’s process is somewhat akin to the Python standard library’s `pickle` module, invoking the low level `__new__` method and then quietly restoring attributes directly on the instance rather than calling `__init__`.
>
> If you need to do some setup on database-loaded instances before they’re ready to use, there is an event hook known as [`InstanceEvents.load()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.load) which can achieve this; it is also available via a class-specific decorator called `orm.reconstructor()`. When using `orm.reconstructor()`, the mapper will invoke the decorated method with no arguments every time it loads or reconstructs an instance of the class. This is useful for recreating transient properties that are normally assigned in `__init__`

So if I've understood you correctly, you could define a reconstructor for `Interaction` that populates the non-ORM fields:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import reconstructor

class Interaction(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'interactions'

    # Mirror the table's structure
    anomaly_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('anomalies.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) # ForeignKey('users.id'),
    feedback_score = Column(Integer)

    # myScoreUpdater is another (non-ORM) object I want this instance to be aware of
    @reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        # Do what you must to populate score updater
        self.myScoreUpdater =  ...
```

Note that you'll probably want to share the logic between the reconstructor and `__init__`, so either just decorate `__init__` as the reconstructor, if it can be called without arguments, or move initialization of score updater to a method.

Finally, if your `ScoperUpdater` does not actually need to know what instance it is bound to, you could just have it as a class attribute shared between all instances – like static attributes in Java.

Comment: Thanks Ilja. I think the part that's stopping me is the "(invoke the decorated method with) no arguments".  I would need a reconstructor that supports this sort of signature: `init_on_load(self, myScoreUpdater)`

Comment: I think your comment and last sentence of your answer is probably the best advice: I should try to re-think my overall architecture